# Identify if all option buttons are unchecked on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 form control option buttons on a sheet. I am trying to set a hard stop before print function if all 4 option buttons have been left unchecked.
I've successfully gotten all my checkboxes (used shapes not form control) to prompt if left blank but am getting nothing for the buttons.

```
If ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("button3") = Unchecked _
And ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("button20") = Unchecked _
And ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("button45") = Unchecked _
And ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("buttonEpic") = Unchecked Then
MsgBox "Missing"
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

I also tried `= False` and `.value = false`. All buttons are currently unchecked but it's not prompting the message box or the hard stop.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30905789/6352151) could help you

Comment: If the optionbutton is checked then `.Value` will be = 1

Comment: thanks for the comment. I'm not having trouble with VBA identifying the form control I don't think. I can check and uncheck the buttons with code, and can get a prompt if not all buttons are checked/true, which will always be the case because only one can be selected at a time.

Comment: Thanks Tim that works when testing one of the buttons while they're checked but `= checked` was also doing the same, so perhaps I'm just not entering the correct line for not being checked/selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a very simple workaround since I am able to identify the checked option button on the worksheet but not if it's un-checked. I just identify if one of the 4 buttons is checked, do nothing if that's true and cancel if false.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint (Cancel as Boolean)

With ActiveSheet
If .Optionbuttons ("button1").Value = Checked _
Or .Optionbuttons ("button2").Value = Checked _
Or .Optionbuttons ("button3").Value = Checked Then
Exit Sub
Else: Msgbox "Please select an option"
Cancel = True
End If
End With
End Sub
```